# Translate C++ to MIPS Assembly

Tags: c++, assembly, mips

I need help with this last part of this problem. I'm basically trying to translate C++ code into MIPS Assembly language.

Assume a is in $s0, b in $s1, c in $s2, x in $s4, y in $s5, and z in $s6.

I finished almost all of them but I am stuck on these two, I know some parts of it but I'm having trouble putting it together as a whole. The parts I know will be followed by hashtags with the assembly code. Thanks for any help.

1.

```
for(x = 0; x <= z; x++) # x = 0; is: addi $s4, $0, 0
y = y + 1; # addi $s5, $s5, 1
y = 0; # addi $s5, $0, 0
```

2.

```
if(y > z)
x = 0; # addi $s4, $0, 0
else x = 1; # else: addi $s4, $0, 1
```

Here are the oringinal problems without the hashtags incase I am wrong:

1.

```
for(x = 0; x <= z; x++) 
y = y + 1; 
y = 0;
```

2.

```
if(y > z) 
x = 0; 
else x = 1;
```

Thanks again.

Attempt at 2, not sure if right.

```
ifLoop:

add $s5, ? , $s6
addi $s4, $0, 0

ifLoop

else:

addi $s4, $0, 1

else
```

Practice: (Assume array p is in $s7)

```
p[0] = 0; 
int a = 2; 
p[1] = a; 
p[a] = a;
```

My attempt:

```
sw $0, 0($s7) 
addiu $s0, $0, 2 
sw $s0, 4($s7) 
sll $t0, $s0, 2 
addu $t1, $t0, $s7 
sw $s0, 0($t1)
```

Comment: A `for` loop and an `if/else` would both require branch instructions (ok, that particular `if/else` could probably be done branchless, but I suspect that you're supposed to use branching anyway), but I see none in your translations. Look up conditional branching in your course material or an online tutorial or a MIPS instruction set reference.

Comment: Yeah, I know that I need branches in there, such as bne, beq, j, etc., however, I'm unsure of where to put them and the correct format which is why I am stuck.

Comment: Your first 3 lines are correct. I'm not familiar with sll, no idea with that line. Remember that ints take up 4 bytes, so p[a] = a in your case is p[2] = 2, so you want to eventually get to this sw $s0, 8($s7). Here's my advice: make a copy of the address located in $s7 into a temp register. Then create a counter that starts at 0. Until this counter == a, keep adding 4 to the copy of $s7. Once they are equal, you are at the address of a.

Comment: @Inertiatic I tried out what you said but ended up just getting more confused lol. I'm not really understanding, sorry. If possible, do you think you can show me what you mean by writing the translated code as I don't think this book shows solutions to even numbers? And if you wan't, you can get rid of the sll since your not familiar with it, I'm just using instructions I read so far in the book. Thanks a lot and sorry for my lack of understanding.

Comment: Start a new question with this problem and comment the link here so we can put this thread to rest. Plus others might chime in.

Comment: @Inertiatic Ok, I started a new question, here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22008565/c-to-assembly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: 1. Luckily it is not much different without pseudo instructions.

```
addi $s4, $0, 0

forLoop: sle $t1, $s4, $s6  #if x <= z, set $t1 to 1, else 0
         addi $s5, $s5, 1
         addi $s5, $0, 0
         addi $s4, $s4 1
         bne $t1, $0, forLoop #repeat loop while $t1 is not 0
```

Here is #2. I just wanted for you to give it a go before I just gave the answer. You want to use the slt instruction to set a register to 1 or 0. If 1, the comparison is true (y > z). Then use bne to determine where to jump to. By comparing the bne to 0, the true code ends up being directly below the bne instruction. For the else, jump to the label.

```
slt $t2, $s6, $s5 # if z < y, set $t2 to 1, else 0
bne $t2, $0, else # if $t2==1, do the code below, if not, go to else

        addi $s4, $0, 0
        j continue    # need the jump instruction to skip the else below
else: 
        addi $s4, $0, 1

continue:
        # rest of code/program
```

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you. One thing though, I forgot to mention I can't use psuedo instructions. Since the li and bgt is considered to be psuedo, what else can I use to replace them, or another way it could be written without psuedo instructions?

Comment: Edited the answer without pseudo instructions. Should make figuring out #2 a breeze.

Comment: Thanks. For the second one I am trying to do it, but I get stuck on the y > z part, I am unsure of what to do. I tried to do parts of it but I'm not sure if its correct: ifLoop:  ?                                                                  addi $s4, $0, 0   ifLoop
else: $s4, $0, 1  else                                                                               Sorry about the formatting, I'm still new and unsure of how to format in a comment lol. I'll just edit the main post with my attempt.

Comment: Edited my answer with the solution to #2.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarifications, it really helped me out and I seem to understand it more clearly now. I'm not sure if this is your area of expertise but its regarding bitwise commands, I was wondering if you could possibly check my work to see if its correct? I uploaded a photo here: http://imgur.com/IgwbqXb Thanks again, I really appreciate your help. If your not familiar with it then that's fine too.

Comment: Glad I could help you understand it. If my answer worked for your problem, please check it as your selected answer. About the bitwise commands, I'm familiar with them, but not confident. It looks like the x | x should = 1 and the x & x should = 1. If I'm understanding the question properly. I would ask a new question, you'll get some good answers for sure.

Comment: Sure thing! I asked before, but some people were saying how this may not be the right forum or section for it or something. But I can ask again. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey sorry, its me again. I was practicing some exercises to sharpen my skill up on translating c++ to mips and was just wondering if I did this example correct. I posted it on my main post on this page if you can take a look at it, that would be appreciated. Thanks again.